# Is there a site to draw a curve and get the equivalent equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I know there are many sites where we can input the equation and get the curve of the function (examples [here](http://fooplot.com), [here](https://graphsketch.com/) and [here](https://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/)).

What I want is the inverse: I have an idea of how I want the curve to be, and want to get to the equation from there. There are some nice lists of curves ([here](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/functions_4.htm)), others not so nice ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves)), but from there is hard to get to the curve I have in mind. That's the curve in this case (in red):

[image: curve]

but there will be many cases when such a software would be very useful. If nobody knows of such a site, then please at least help me identify the equation for the curve above.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for someone to create an interpolation app.  For the curve you drew, does it continue horizontally in each direction, or does it continue upwards/downwards?

Comment: If it doesn't exist yet, yes. It would be very useful for some tasks (like create simulation games).

Comment: This looks like a sine curve $\sin(2\pi\frac{x}{4})$ added to a straight line. In particular $y = -\frac{1}{4}x + 1 + A \sin(2\pi\frac{x}{4})$, with maybe $A = 0.15$!

Comment: My thought would be something like $y^{2n-1}=x$ with an appropriate offset for that curve

Comment: @abiessu The continuation you refer to doesn't make much sense in my simulation. It could continue as a horizontal line, or aproach y=0 and y=1, like a limit.

Comment: @Weaam Your example worked perfectly, thanks! http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIteC80KzErMC4xNSpzaW4ocGkqeC8yKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIjAiLCI0IiwiMCIsIjEiXX1d

Comment: If it continues horizontally, then you are looking at something like $x=\tan y$...

Comment: Actually, it *could* continue horizontally. But I'm not worried about it. My domain now is between 0 and 4. Thank you, @abiessu.

Comment: @Weaam, please put your solution as an answer, so I'll accept it in two days, if no one shows such a website.

Comment: @Weaam Please add your solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the line is $y = -\frac{1}{4}x + 1$, and the curve looks like a sine curve $y = \sin⁡(\frac{2 \pi x}{4})$ (where x is scaled so that it makes a cycle from 0 to 4) added to that line. Therefore,

$$y=−\frac{1}{4}x+1+A \sin(2\pi \frac{x}{4})$$ 
but the amplitude $A$ is tricky from the figure, so perhaps choose $A=0.15$.

Answer (score 2):

Your curve appears to be the [cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) parametrized by
$$
p(t) = (1 - t)^{3}\, p_{1} + 3(1 - t)^{2}t\, p_{2} + 3(1 - t)t^{2}\, p_{3} + t^{3}\, p_{4},\quad 0 \leq t \leq 1,
$$
with $p_{1} = (0, 1)$, $p_{2} = (\frac{8}{3}, 1)$, $p_{3} = (\frac{4}{3}, 0)$, $p_{4} = (4, 0)$.

[Dmitry Baranovskiy](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy)'s [Raphaël](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael) JavaScript library has an [interactive demo](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/curver.html) for drawing splines.

[image: A cubic spline]

Comment: Thanks, but Weaam solution above seems easier to implement, and fits perfectly to my curve.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
$y=\frac{1+\cos{\frac{\pi·x}4}}2$
$====================$
RODRIGO'S COMMENT:
Very good, Senex, thank you. But I like Weaam solution more, because I have more control to adjust it (closer to a sinoid vs. closer to a straight line). – Rodrigo
$====================$
EDIT PURSUANT TO RODRIGO'S COMMENT (2016·3·6):
Well, try this then:
C and L are weights to control how much influence the cosine curve and the straight line, respectively, will have in the shape of your desired curve.

examples:
$C=1\;\text{and}\;L=0\;\text{will give you the curve in my original presentation.}$
$C=0\;\text{and}\;L=1\;\text{will give you the pure straight line.}$
$C=1\;\text{and}\;L=1$
$\;\text{will give you a curve in which the two influences are balanced.}$
Other combinations of C and L will yield other results.

$y=\frac{C·\frac12·\left(1+\cos{\frac{\pi·x}4}\right)+L·\frac{4-x}4}{C+L}$

Comment: Very good, Senex, thank you. But I like Weaam solution more, because I have more control to adjust it (closer to a sinoid vs. closer to a straight line).